# Error Repeated "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, error-handling

When I try to run this basic app I get the "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'."

gradle.build (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hellokotlinandroid.gohool.com.buttonstextviewedittext"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

}
```

gradle.build (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.0-RC'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
```

**This is the full error**

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.6.0-RC.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://maven.google.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.6.0-RC/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.6.0-RC.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.6.0-RC/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.6.0-RC.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.6.0-RC/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.6.0-RC.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

This error is repeated multiple times, 17 to be exact and is the same thing but with a slightly different task each time

I have already looked through forums and tried what they say but cannot seem to find anything and have tried all basic troubleshooting
Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got same issue, in my case i did these following

`kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "1.8" }`

```
change to
```

`kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "11" }`

Basically change from jdk 1.8 to 11. Or by **Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK (change to 11 or Embedded JDK)**.

Clean Project and Rebuild Project.

Comment: Didnt work for me. Already was pointing to JDK 11